# Missing 64-bit support when uploading to appStore

Tags: xcode, app-store

When I am trying to upload my code to appStore I met this issue. and I have tried to set Active Architecture to NO according to some search. but the issue is still there. I noticed that in my project, by default I can not see "arm64" in "Valid Architectures" entry. only "armv7 armv7s", why? if I add arm64 to that entry, I got a lot of compiling issue like " implicit declaration of function 'bcopy' is invalid in C99".

Any ideas about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if answer it but:

Apple just announced that starting 1. February 2015, apps have to [support 64 bit](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a). So, it will then be a requirement.

Then maybe shown errors was because you have statements no compatible with 64 bits architecture.

Comment: you are right. I changed valid architecture and added arm64 manually. then compiled my project again, I found one issue in "Report Navigator", not in "Issue Navigator". so I changed my code to mute the error. then it's passed. thanks！